# Create SOAP message from WSDL using axiom

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, axiom

I'm a starting a project which consist in sending a request to a web-service (which is already available) and parsing the response. I have the WSDL and URL endpoints. Does anyone have a startup tutorial on how to build something from there?

I would like to use Axis2 + Axiom to send the service request and receive and process the response. I'm using eclipse as dev env. I've been search for a tut on how to do this but with no success.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help you

[creating a webservice client using eclipse](http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html)

Comment: it was not working for me... :( I found something based on your response.

Comment: This is why link based answers are discouraged ... Broken link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Axiom, but [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a terrific tool for testing web services in just the manner you describe.

I don't know if Eclipse has a plug-in for it.  (They do for everything else.)  IntelliJ supports it, so that's how I use it.

Answer (score 1):

Well in conclusion, I did find two very useful links for the Apache axis2 project, got it working in no time!

A deep explanation Invoking Web Services using Apache Axis2:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/12/13/invoking-web-services-using-apache-axis2.html

For code generation from WSDL:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html